# Jasper server webapp in Iframe logs out after successful login (Chrome/Edge browsers)

Tags: iframe, jasperserver

I have a jasper server (versions 7.2) webapp running on Host-A.
Set the jasper server url source in Iframe of another app running on Host-B.
Access the Iframe app using Chrome/Edge - login page of jasper server loads.
After login credentials input, login is successful loads the Home page but logs out moment after the home page appears.

This does not happen with Firefox.
Tried disabling CSRF in Jasper server, setting samesite cookies enabling ssl, setting Referrer policy to no-referrer via Filters at both jasper server and Iframe app but no luck.

Chrome latest build 87.

Please guide under right direction to resolve the problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm highly suspicious of same-site issues since the problem occurs in chrome & edge but not firefox.  A patch or config change is needed for the newer version of chrome: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/chromium-80-update-february-2020-cross-site-cookie-blocking-jaspersoft

Also, if the problem was CSRF, you'd see a CSRF related msg in the server-side logs.

Browser Developer Tools (f12 keyboard key in WIN) for chrome will list the http requests/responses in the network tab, and allow you to check the attributes for each cookie.  Of course SSL is required for samesite attrs now in Chrome.

While confirming the appropriate cookie attributes are set (esp on the jsessionid cookie) you can also watch the console tab in chrome's Developer Tools to ensure there are no other client-side clues (like mixed http/https content, CORS blocks, etc)